# android store arraylist in txt file

Tags: android, arrays, list

i am newbie in Android from play class i want to store Question ArrayList and AnswerArrayList both in a Txt file, but i have not done this before and not really sure how to do it.. here is the java code below:

**Java**

```
public class play extends Activity  {

private Question currentQuestion;
private int currentQuestionIndex;
private ArrayList<Button> questionButton;
private TextView questionstextview;
private TextView questionnumber;
private TextView playerfeedback;
public static TextView displayscore;
public static int score;
private List<Question> QuestionList;
private int answerchoice; 
public static int totalanswer;
public static int correctanswer;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.play);
        Log.i("playclass", "this is play class running");

        questionButton = new ArrayList<Button>();       
        questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton1));
        questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton2));
        questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton3));
        questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton4));
        currentQuestion = null;
        currentQuestionIndex = 0;

        QuestionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        ArrayList <String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();

        answer.add("8");
        answer.add("9");
        answer.add("3");
        answer.add("1");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 4+4", answer, 0));

        ArrayList <String> answer1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        answer1.add("17");
        answer1.add("20");
        answer1.add("15");
        answer1.add("14");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 7+8?", answer1, 3));

       ArrayList <String> answer2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        answer2.add("20");
        answer2.add("30");
        answer2.add("19");
        answer2.add("34");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 10+10?", answer2, 0));

        ArrayList <String> answer3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        answer3.add("12");
        answer3.add("11");
        answer3.add("13");
        answer3.add("14");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 6+6?", answer3, 0));

        ArrayList <String> answer4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        answer4.add("6");
        answer4.add("5");
        answer4.add("4");
        answer4.add("7");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 4+3?", answer4, 3));

        ArrayList <String> answer5 = new ArrayList<String>();
        answer5.add("7");
        answer5.add("9");
        answer5.add("10");
        answer5.add("11");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 3+7?", answer5, 2));








        questionstextview = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.questionstextview);           
        questionnumber = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.questionnumber);        
        displayscore = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.displayscore);
        displayscore.setText(Integer.toString(score));

        StartTrivia();
    }
public void ButtonPress (View answerButton){

    MediaPlayer soundfx = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.click);

    soundfx.start();

    for (int i=0; i< questionButton.size(); i++)
    {   


        if (questionButton.get(i) ==answerButton)

        {   

         if (i==currentQuestion.getAnswerIndex())

          { 
             score+=5;
             displayscore.setText(Integer.toString(score));


             correctanswer++;
             totalanswer++;


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        else{

            totalanswer++;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Log.i("playclass", "after incorrect toast");
        }

            currentQuestionIndex++;


             Log.i("playclass", "after currentQuestionIndex++; ");

            if (currentQuestionIndex < QuestionList.size()){

                Log.i("playclass", "after currentQuestionIndex < QuestionList.size() ");
                StartTrivia();
                Log.i("playclass", "after StartTrivia in if statement ");
            }

            else{

                Intent result = new Intent (this, finalscreen.class);
                startActivity(result);
                Log.i("playclass", "after IntentResult ");
            }
            break;
         }

    }   
}

public void StartTrivia(){

    Log.i("playclass", "running StartTrivia() " + currentQuestionIndex); 

    currentQuestion = QuestionList.get(currentQuestionIndex); 

    questionstextview.setText(currentQuestion.getquestion());

    questionnumber.setText(Integer.toString(currentQuestionIndex+0));

    for (int i = 0; i < questionButton.size(); i++)

     { 

         String ans = currentQuestion.getanswer().get(i); 
         questionButton.get(i).setText(ans);

     }

    }
```

}

Comment: have you considered storing the data in database instead using sqlite?

Comment: the database implementation on android IS sqlite...

Comment: i know but would it be possible to use txt file?